# how to run a scheduler.rake file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rake

I am new in rails arena. Just did my first project by myself with rails from the scratch. And, now I have to work in a 2nd project which is done by someone else.

In this project, there is a file named scheduler.rake under the /lib/tasks directory.

It's being used for cron job as far as I understood. I need to make some modifications and add some new features to this project. So, I need to run this scheduler.rake file and have to understand how it works. Could anyone please help me with how to run such a rake scheduler in rails and how does it work exactly?
Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I tried with: rake data:import command. But rake is aborted. Really need to find some way to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your scheduler.rake file ?

Comment: @K.M.RakibulIslam just like you `run rake db:create` or `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:seed`

Comment: The  part of the rake file is :    desc "Everything is combined into a big scrape starting at 3:00am UTC"
task :scrape => :environment do
  date = Date.today-1
  
  if ![0,6].include? date.wday #check that yesterday wasn't a weekend day
    puts "Options:"
    begin
      scraper = OptionScraper.new
      scraper.scrape(date)
      scraper.add_to_database
    rescue => e
      RakeErrorMessage.create(:message => e.message, :backtrace => e.backtrace.join("\n"))
    end
  end

Comment: thanks everyone for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tasks from lib/tasks could be listed by the command:

```
rake -T
```

If you don't see your command in the response list then it is not well formed or just does not have description.
So you need to investigate your rake file.
Rake tasks files have similar structure, like:

```
namespace :some_task do

  task :do_some_work => :environment do
    # Code goes here
  end

  desc 'Do some other work'
  task :do_something => :environment do
    # Code goes here
  end

end
```

In this code, there is two tasks and each of them could be executed like this:

```
#first task
rake some_task:do_some_work

#second task
rake some_task:do_something
```

Sometimes there could be no namespace and then tasks could be executed just using rake command and name of the task as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

just try this will run the rake task

```
      rake scheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to understand it, you'd rather read the code in the task file than run it.

The rake file has nothing but ruby code in it (in a special dsl).

It also pays to know about rake if you are into Rails. Here's a [Rake Intro video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFPWDzHWjEY) by its creator Jim Weirich.

Answer (score -1):

You have to understand `rake` first. Rake is a build tool, written in Ruby, using Ruby as a build language. Rake supports rule patterns to sythesize implicit tasks. Jason Seifer has an excellent [walkthrough on rake](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial).

Comment: The link to the walkthrough is broken. A search on the site also turns up empty and without any rake tutorial.